# Shutdown does not clean the state of the drive

Tags: dual-boot, windows, shutdown, drive

I was not sure whether to ask this in *superuser* or here. Anyway, I have dual boot: Win 8 and Ubuntu 14.04 and 3 disk drives:

1. for Windows OS (the famous C://)
2. neutral one, for files (lets call it "D drive")
3. for Linux (Ubuntu is installed solely on this one)

When I **restart** from Windows and go in Linux, I can open D drive, but if I **shutdown** from Windows - I cannot open D drive in Linux. It gives me an error saying that the drive is in an unsafe state - the same as if I hibernate from Windows. The hibernation I understand why, but isn't the shutdown supposed to clear the state of the drive (as the restart does)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable fast start up feature on Windows 8. For that do the following.

Go to `Control Panel` > `Hardware and Sound` > `Power Options` > `System Setting` > Choose what the power buttons do and uncheck the Turn on fast startup box.

Reference: http://itsfoss.com/solve-ntfs-mount-problem-ubuntu-windows-8-dual-boot/

Comment: I am talking about shutting the computer down, softwarely, like complete shutdown of the system, but not sleep/hibernating the system.

Comment: During shutdown, if the fast start up is enabled in widnows 8, then it will store some data about the state of all mounted partitions at the time of turn off in to a file. This will prevent ubuntu to mount that partition.

Comment: Refer the link I have shared. that will give you a better understanding.